# WilfFly and NetBeans settings for development

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, settings, wildfly

I would like to ask if you could give me some tips how to setup WildFly with netbeans into something like development mode.

I have netbeans 8.0 and WildFly setup. But if I make changes in project and save them my setup immediately redeploys these changes. This is fine but this redeploy takes up to 30 - 40 seconds sometimes even more. I would like to ask if there are some settings that only changed the changed code on the server and wouldnt do complete redeploy.

I'm using Apache Maven too.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution for me. It is JRebel. After installation it updates the project in 2-3 seconds.